# How to get .m3u8 link from embed link using a webview

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview, android-videoview, webviewclient

I am a new to Android development and I want to get .m3u8 link from embedded link of dailymotion, yet I am using a webview client but I don't how it possible.

My code is:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity implements DownloadListener {

    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "WebViewActivity";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    WebViewActivity myContxt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);


        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        myContxt=this;

        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(myContxt, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(myContxt,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                Log.w(TAG,url);
                webview.setDownloadListener(myContxt);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                Log.w(TAG,url);
                if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
                progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(myContxt, "Application Name", "Loading...");
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.w(TAG,url);
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                Toast.makeText(myContxt, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2bnb3s");


    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Log.w("m3u8888",url);
    }
```